# where to get an on-arrival COVID-19 PCR test in Jordan?

Tags: covid-19, jordan

According to https://jo.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/ visitors to Jordan need to "*Conduct a PCR test on arrival in Jordan with the payment of JD 28*". My question is... how do I get a PCR test on arrival? Do they have them at the airport? If not then I guess I'd need to find a clinic and go to one? https://www.gov.uk/find-travel-test-provider lets you find test providers online for the UK...  is there a similar service for Jordan?

Comment: "where to get a negative COVID-19 PCR test in Jordan?" You make a test and hope to be negative!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.